# android studio - How To filter & show data with datepicker

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, datepicker, show

i have data Policy ID, and i want it show by filter such as date...
in my project i have 1 layout to select date, by using datepicker..and i hope when i select date, and Click button "show data", data will show in 1 another layout using recycler view.FYI, before this i have try to show my data Policy ID selected by Policy ID and success, but without filter by date..im so frustrating for this, please help me..sorry for my bad english :(

this is my DatePickerActivity.xml :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".DatePickerActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/picDate"
        android:text="Pic Date"
        android:onClick="datePicker"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/picDate"
        android:id="@+id/showDate"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/showDate"
        android:id="@+id/showDataPicker"
        android:text="Show Data"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my DatePickerActivity.Java :

```js
package id.intraasia.intraasiaagent;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;


public class DatePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @BindView(R.id.showDataPicker)
    Button showDataPicker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_picker);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


    }

    public void datePicker(View view) {
        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
    }

    public void setDate(final Calendar calendar) {
        final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.showDate)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        setDate(calendar);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.showDataPicker)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }

    }


}
```

this is my PolicyActivy.java (when i success try to show any data by Policy ID)

```js
public class PolicyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;
    List<PolicyNo> policyNo = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG = PolicyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String policyno;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PolicyAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_policy);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.policy_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        ApiEndPoint apiEndPoint =
                ApiClient.getClient(this).create(ApiEndPoint.class);

        Call<PolicyStatus> call = apiEndPoint.getPolicyNo(policyno);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PolicyStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PolicyStatus> call, Response<PolicyStatus> response) {
                policyNo = response.body().getPolicyNo();
                Log.d(TAG, "Number Policy Received: " + policyNo.size());
                adapter = new PolicyAdapter(policyNo,R.layout.list_item_policy, getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PolicyStatus> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchfile, menu);
        final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        changeSearchViewTextColor(searchView);
        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)).setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
                myActionMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                final List<PolicyNo> filtermodelist= filter(policyNo, newText);
                adapter.setFilter(filtermodelist);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private List<PolicyNo> filter(List<PolicyNo> policyNo, String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<PolicyNo> filteredModeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PolicyNo model: policyNo) {
            final String text = model.getPolicyNo().toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(query)) {
                filteredModeList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModeList;
    }

    private void changeSearchViewTextColor(View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                return;
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    changeSearchViewTextColor(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

policyadapter :(when i success try to show any data by Policy ID)

```js
public class PolicyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder> {


    private List<PolicyNo> policyNo;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class PolicyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout policyLayout;
        TextView nomorpolis;

        public PolicyViewHolder (View v){
            super(v);
            policyLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.policy_layout);
            nomorpolis = v.findViewById(R.id.nomorpolis);
        }
    }
    public PolicyAdapter (List<PolicyNo>policyNo, int rowLayout, Context context){
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
        this.context = context;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }
    @Override
    public PolicyAdapter.PolicyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new PolicyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder (PolicyViewHolder holder, final int position){
        holder.nomorpolis.setText(policyNo.get(position).getPolicyNo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return policyNo.size();}

    public void setFilter(List<PolicyNo> policyNoList)
    {
        policyNo = new ArrayList<>();
        policyNo.addAll(policyNoList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

this is my activity.policy.xml (my plan this layout to store data, when datepicker was selected)

```js
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_policy"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context="id.intraasia.intraasiaagent.PolicyActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/policy_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

this is my list_item_policy.xml (my plan this layout to store data, when datepicker was selected)

```js
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/policy_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/Orange">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nopolis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No Policy :"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nomorpolis"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/nomorpolis"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

AdateOri.Java:

```js
public class ADateOri {

    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("timezone_type")
    @Expose
    private Integer timezoneType;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    @Expose
    private String timezone;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Integer getTimezoneType() {
        return timezoneType;
    }

    public void setTimezoneType(Integer timezoneType) {
        this.timezoneType = timezoneType;
    }

    public String getTimezone() {
        return timezone;
    }

    public void setTimezone(String timezone) {
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

}
```

PolicyNo.java :

```js
public class PolicyNo {

    @SerializedName("ANO")
    @Expose
    private Integer aNO;
    @SerializedName("pANO")
    @Expose
    private Integer pANO;
    @SerializedName("PolicyNo")
    @Expose
    private String policyNo;
    @SerializedName("AName")
    @Expose
    private String aName;
    @SerializedName("EffectiveDT")
    @Expose
    private String effectiveDT;
    @SerializedName("ADATE")
    @Expose
    private String aDATE;
    @SerializedName("ADateOri")
    @Expose
    private ADateOri aDateOri;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC1")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC1;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC2")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC2;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC3")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC3;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC4")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC4;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC5")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC5;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC6")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC6;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC7")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC7;
    @SerializedName("VALUEDESC9")
    @Expose
    private String vALUEDESC9;
    @SerializedName("TSI")
    @Expose
    private Integer tSI;
    @SerializedName("ASTATUS")
    @Expose
    private String aSTATUS;
    @SerializedName("ATYPE")
    @Expose
    private String aTYPE;

    public Integer getANO() {
        return aNO;
    }

    public void setANO(Integer aNO) {
        this.aNO = aNO;
    }

    public Integer getPANO() {
        return pANO;
    }

    public void setPANO(Integer pANO) {
        this.pANO = pANO;
    }

    public String getPolicyNo() {
        return policyNo;
    }

    public void setPolicyNo(String policyNo) {
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
    }

    public String getAName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setAName(String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }

    public String getEffectiveDT() {
        return effectiveDT;
    }

    public void setEffectiveDT(String effectiveDT) {
        this.effectiveDT = effectiveDT;
    }

    public String getADATE() {
        return aDATE;
    }

    public void setADATE(String aDATE) {
        this.aDATE = aDATE;
    }

    public ADateOri getADateOri() {
        return aDateOri;
    }

    public void setADateOri(ADateOri aDateOri) {
        this.aDateOri = aDateOri;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC1() {
        return vALUEDESC1;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC1(String vALUEDESC1) {
        this.vALUEDESC1 = vALUEDESC1;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC2() {
        return vALUEDESC2;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC2(String vALUEDESC2) {
        this.vALUEDESC2 = vALUEDESC2;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC3() {
        return vALUEDESC3;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC3(String vALUEDESC3) {
        this.vALUEDESC3 = vALUEDESC3;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC4() {
        return vALUEDESC4;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC4(String vALUEDESC4) {
        this.vALUEDESC4 = vALUEDESC4;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC5() {return vALUEDESC5;}

    public void setVALUEDESC5(String vALUEDESC5) {
        this.vALUEDESC5 = vALUEDESC5;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC6() {
        return vALUEDESC6;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC6(String vALUEDESC6) {
        this.vALUEDESC6 = vALUEDESC6;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC7() {
        return vALUEDESC7;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC7(String vALUEDESC7) {
        this.vALUEDESC7 = vALUEDESC7;
    }

    public String getVALUEDESC9() {
        return vALUEDESC9;
    }

    public void setVALUEDESC9(String vALUEDESC9) {
        this.vALUEDESC9 = vALUEDESC9;
    }

    public Integer getTSI() {
        return tSI;
    }

    public void setTSI(Integer tSI) {
        this.tSI = tSI;
    }

    public String getASTATUS() {
        return aSTATUS;
    }

    public void setASTATUS(String aSTATUS) {
        this.aSTATUS = aSTATUS;
    }

    public String getATYPE() {
        return aTYPE;
    }

    public void setATYPE(String aTYPE) {
        this.aTYPE = aTYPE;
    }

    public PolicyNo(String policyNo) {
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
    }


}
```

PolicyStatus.java :

```js
public class PolicyStatus {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private Boolean success;
    @SerializedName("PolicyNo")
    @Expose
    private List<PolicyNo> policyNo = null;

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<PolicyNo> getPolicyNo() {
        return policyNo;
    }

    public void setPolicyNo(List<PolicyNo> policyNo) {
        this.policyNo = policyNo;
    }

}
```

if information above unclear/uncomplete please to ask to me..i'll be give any information to u for helping me...thank u

Comment: if you want to show a record date wise then make server side change when u pass for particular define format date then server given only those date record. that time easy to show a record date wise other make custom logic for show date wise record.

Comment: im already use server side...with php..FYI, i'm already using this filter by date to date to build in web application..but i dont understand how to implement in android studio..can u help me?